# match everything up to first '/' after a specific pattern

Tags: regex, awk, sed

Trying to do this within a bash script using sed regex on macos. I have a file with directory listings of an external drive.

```
/Volumes/WD/A/Some Learning/Learning Is Great/
/Volumes/WD/A/Some Deeper/Learning Is Great/Another Learning Opportunity/
/Volumes/WD/B/More Things Here/Great Learning/
/Volumes/WD/B/More Things/
```

I want to search and return the top-most directory matching various patterns. If you search for 'Learning' the output should be:

```
/Volumes/WD/A/Some Learning/
/Volumes/WD/A/Some Deeper/Learning Is Great/
/Volumes/WD/B/More Things Here/Great Learning/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 's/\(Learning[^/]*\/\).*/\1/p' file
```

Turn off implicit printing by using the `-n` option. Then using the substitution command and its `p` flag to print on a successful replacement of the string `Learning` to the next occurrence of a `/`, grouped by `\(...\)` and referred to `\1` (in the replacement) to the end of the file by the back reference `\1` only. All other lines will not be printed out.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are ok with `awk` could you please try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/Learning[^\/]*\//){print substr($0,1,RSTART+RLENGTH-1)}' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
/Volumes/WD/A/Some Learning/
/Volumes/WD/A/Some Deeper/Learning Is Great/
/Volumes/WD/B/More Things Here/Great Learning/
```

Comment: Additionally, I think if anyone can still provide a matching sed expression it will help the community. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mind showing me what changes are needed if I wanted to echo a string and use awk with the expression above within a bash script? echo 'str' | awk <command> works command line, but not in a shell script. I am trying to do this in a bash script so $0 becomes an issue. The idea is to read through each directory listed in the file, as a string, and check if it contains a specific pattern. If it does, output the top-most matching directory.

Comment: The sed expression was more in-line with my request, so I am accepting that. However, it's also great to see two equivalent ways to solve the same problem; albeit, understanding the caveats.

Comment: Yeah, I did not have the voting or notify privilege until your comment was posted. I did vote up your helpful answer. Also, I did all this switching after reading [is-it-poor-form-to-switch-accepted-answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62252/is-it-poor-form-to-switch-accepted-answers) and following the suggestion in the comment. It would be great if someone can still explain how to work around the $0 bash script conflict issue when working with the awk solution provided. And yes, I did learn from your awk expression, so many thanks!

Comment: @SandeepJ, switching an answer to another good answer is never an issue for anyone. For new question please open a new thread, one question per thread please cheers and happy learning.