# print match and apply transformation to each match

Tags: bash, macos, awk, sed

An extension to my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59163753/match-everything-up-to-first-after-a-specific-pattern). The below sed output generated already matches a specific pattern of files: `[Ll]earning`

```
grep [Ll]earning <file>
<match output is...>

/Volumes/WD/A/machinelearning-2018-12-01-07_26_05.pdf
/Volumes/WD/A/SomeLearningIsGood/Path/machinelearning-2018-12-01-07_26_05.pdf
```

I want to transform the output above to include and append a transformation, at each match-level (sed/awk). The transformation identifies the path to the left-most directory that matches the pattern (if any). The delimiter can be anything like ":". If there is no left-most matching directory for the pattern `[Ll]earning`, print 0, else print up to the left-most directory. "/Volumes/WD/A/SomeLearningIsGood/" in the 2nd match above is the left-most matching directory in path structure, so it is appended to its respective file-pattern match.

```
<expected output>

/Volumes/WD/A/machinelearning-2018-12-01-07_26_05.pdf : 0
/Volumes/WD/A/SomeLearningIsGood/Path/machinelearning-2018-12-01-07_26_05.pdf : /Volumes/WD/A/SomeLearningIsGood/
```

I am aware that the actual expression to show left-most matching dir is:

```
sed -n 's/\([Ll]earning[^/]*\/\).*/\1/p' file

matches:
/Volumes/WD/A/SomeLearningIsGood/
```

**Update**
Trying to do this on Mac OS X (BSD sed/awk) within bash 3 script. Issues running on BSD sed. See Update 2.

**Update 2**
Install gsed (GNU sed) via MacPorts/Homebrew and follow the solution from @Aaron. Works like a charm.

```
brew install gnu-sed
port install gsed
```

Comment: Not quite what you want, but printing the leading path on only the matching lines could be done with `sed -n '/[Ll]earning/s~\(^.*/[Ll]earning/\).*~&: \1~p' file`

Comment: @cmbuckley echo '/Volumes/WD/A/machinelearning-2018-12-01-07_26_05.pdf' | sed -n '/[Ll]earning/s~\(^.*/[Ll]earning/\).*~&: \1~p' is empty? It does work on the 2nd file though.

Comment: That's why I say it's not quite what you want :)

Comment: Yeah, conditional logic may require an awk expression.

Comment: What should be the output for `/Volumes/MachineLearningCourses/noname.com/ml-101.pdf`?  Should the part after the colon be `/Volumes/MachineLearningCourses/noname.com`?  Or does it not count because the path element isn't `…/Learning/…`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well, the filename should have the matching '[Ll]earning' expression already (ie. pre-filtered) which yours does not. If the filename did have the expression, the top-most matching directory would be '/Volumes/MachineLearningCourses/'.

Comment: The illustrated `grep '[lL]earning'` in the question would match the name I showed.  You'd need `grep -E -e '.*/[^/]*[lL]earning[^/]*$'` or thereabouts to look for the  'learning' or 'Learning' in the last component of the pathname.  However, change my `ml-101.pdf` to `machine-learning-101.pdf` and you seem to be wanting the path up to the first component that contains 'learning'.  So, with `/Volumes/Learning/MachineLearningCourses/noname.com/machine-learning-101.pdf`, you'd want `/Volumes/Learning` as the path after the colon, rather than `/Volumes/Learning/MachineLearningCourses/`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler My apologies. I stand corrected. To further clarify, at a minimum, assume the filenames already have the pattern "[Ll]earning". I have also updated my example to reflect the top-most matching dir in a similar case to your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for:

```
sed -En '\@[Ll]earning[^/]*/@{h;s@([Ll]earning[^/]*/).*@\1@;H;x;s/\n/ : /p;t};s/.*[Ll]earning.*/& : 0/p'
```

No need for a `grep` beforehand, it filters out the results without [Ll]earning.

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/6tddel).

Here's a POSIX-compliant alternative:

```
sed -n '/[Ll]earning[^\/]*\//{h;s/\([Ll]earning[^\/]*\/\).*/\1/;H;x;s/\n/ : /p;t};s/.*[Ll]earning.*/& : 0/p'
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/KHtnea).

Also check [potong's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59200187/print-match-and-apply-transformation-to-each-match/comments#comment104646190_59201400) if you don't need to filter out lines without `[Ll]earning`, it's much simpler !

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203717/discussion-on-answer-by-aaron-print-match-and-apply-transformation-to-each-match).

Comment: Perhaps easier on the eye `sed -E '/^(.*[Li]earning[^/]*\/).*/s//& : \1/;t;s/$/ : 0/' file`

Comment: @potong same problem as my original answer : when there's two `/.*[Ll]earning.*/` dir it returns the deepest one, while OP wants the top-most one. That makes things quite ugly...

Comment: @Aaron I see! An alternative then: `sed -E '/[Ll]earning[^/]*\//!s/$/ : 0/;t;s//&\n/;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\1\2 : \1/' file`

Comment: @potong there's a difference still in that it doesn't filter out lines paths without `[Ll]earning`, but I believe OP doesn't care about them as he uses a `grep` before.